# reference from typegoose model to mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In legacy project we are migrating to typegoose. 
Right now it has mongoose models and
I need to reference from typegoose to the old mongoose models.

An example mongoose model:

```
export interface User extends Mongoose.Document {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
}

const userSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    FirstName: String,
    LastName: String,
}, {strict: false, versionKey: false});

export default Mongoose.model<User>('users', userSchema);
```

Now I created a typegoose model:

```
import UserModel, {User} from "./user";

export class Branch extends Typegoose {
    @prop({ref: UserModel})
    owner?: Ref<User>;
    @prop()
    name: string;
}
export const BranchModel = new Branch().getModelForClass(Branch);
```

I don't know how to fetch the branches user.
I try to populate `BranchModel.find({}).populate({path: "user"})`
but I get the error `Schema hasn't been registered for model \"model\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)","stack":"MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model \"model\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I'm late replying to this, but I think you have two separate instances of mongoose in your application. I'm hoping in your legacy application, you're explicitly creating a mongoose instance on startup and Typegoose uses its own mongoose instance that I think is implicitly created by Typegoose.

In your case, you have to supply the existing mongoose instance to the getModelForClass method in the second argument as below

```
export const BranchModel = new Branch().getModelForClass(Branch, {existingMongoose: legacyMongooseInstance});
```

That should use the same mongoose instance and the Typegoose generated Schema can "see" the "legacy" schema. Refer the documentation of Typegoose.